# PKI HSM Simulator

Tags: algorithm, digital-signature, hmac, pki

Anyone aware of PKI HSM simulator for windows.Found **openCryptoki**, but it for linux only. 
Need to test digital signature and then validate using the suitable algorithum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [SoftHSM](http://www.opendnssec.org/softhsm/), but I'm not sure you'll be able run on the Windows.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/softhsm4windows/